# Sending events from Celery task - Flask-SocketIO + Celery

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to send events from a Celery task to the server, so I can send data to the Client.

[image]

1. A User submits a form with text
2. The server receives the form submission
3. The server sends the form data to the Celery task queue
4. Celery processes the task
5. Celery sends the processed data back to the server
6. The server sends the data to the Client, where it's displayed on the web page

Here is what I have currently:

```
routes.py

@main_bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = UserTextForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_data = request.form.to_dict()

        user_text = request_data['user_text']

        run_processing_task.apply_async(args=[user_text])

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@socketio.on('my_event', namespace='/user_text_task_results')
def user_test_task_results(my_event):
    # Sends data to client
    send(my_event, broadcast=True)
```

```
celery_tasks.py

@celery.task(bind=True)
def run_processing_task(self, user_text):
    print('Celery Function kicked off')

    local_socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://localhost:6379/0')

    time.sleep(3)
    user_text_reverse = user_text[::-1]
    local_socketio.emit('my_event', {'data': user_text_reverse}, namespace='/user_text_task_results')

    print('Task Completed')

    return 'Finished'
```

```
index.html

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</head>


<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main_bp.index') }}" class="col-6">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.user_text(class="form-control", id="user-text-area") }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="test-app">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.send('User Connected')
        });

        socket.on('message', function(results){
            var reversed_text = results['data']
            $("$test-app").append('<p>'+reversed_text+</p>)
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run the above, the task is processed, but I don't think the server receives the data `local_socketio.emit(...)`. I can see that the Celery task finishes successfully, but I don't see anything to indicate the data is flowing through to the server and ultimately the client.

I tried installing gevent and gevent-websocket, but then the index won't event load for the initial GET request (it just hangs in a loading state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery workers typically run the same code as the Flask app, but they not running as flask servers, so websockets from celery to flask aren't easily a thing. (I've never seen it done, but maybe someone has ironed out the tricky parts.)

Assuming that you want to avoid having the client or app poll for task completion, an alternative is to have the worker signal completion by making an HTTP request to the app. I.e., something like a POST to

```
/tasks/complete/<task_id>
```

Then it's a app issue have done the bookkeeping to associate a `task_id` with a particular websocket.

**Adding:**

Celery has a [post_run](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-postrun) signal that is supposed to serve the same purpose. I didn't have luck with it a few years ago, but am now thinking I did something dumb.

Comment: Yes, I think this makes more sense actually- it doesn't seem there's any reason Celery needs to send the task results via websocket. The only thing I'm having trouble with now is sending a socketio message via the general application route that receives the POST request, without using the @socketio decorator

Comment: Heyo, I was wondering if either of you guys used Server Side Events with Celery workers? I am not able to find much about it online so perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree but for my use case long polling is bad for scaling. Thoughts?

Comment: Haven't tried that.